# Trying to override a CSS property on the Bootstrap 5 Fluid-container class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've applied padding of 7% top/bottom and 15% left/right to the Bootstrap5 class container-fluid using the following:

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 7% 15%
}
```

This works fine but I'm trying to override this for my title section to have less padding on the top but it is having no effect. I am using the following:

```
#title.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15% 7%;
}
```

this is exactly how its being done in a tutorial I'm watching, but it wont work for me. I'm wondering if it might be a Bootstrap 5 change as i think the tutorial is in bootstrap 4

Comment: show us the html that goes with the css.  also, since id's are unique you just need #title or do you really mean #title .container-fluid?

Comment: That was it! I didn't have the space between #title and .container-fluid. My apologies for such a silly error. I really appreciate your help, I search all over for an answer but didnt know how to precisely word my issue so i couldn't get any kind of relevant answer. Thx so much @DCR !!